# to bail out vs to back out

Tags: terminology

In a CS context, I have often come across the expression *to back out* meaning to say that a function is returned from before performing its actual task, as in this imaginary code comment:

```
double divide(double dividend, double divisor) {
  if (divisor == 0) {
    return 0; //divisor is zero => back out early
  }
  return (dividend / divisor);
}
```

Now I recently came across the expression *to bail out* in just the very same context. I know that *to bail somebody out* generally means *to provide funds to get someone out of a difficult financial situation*, so I was wondering if the writer confused *to back out* and *to bail out* or if *to bail out* really has this meaning, too.

Has any one ever heard or read a native speaker of English say or write *to bail out of a function*? Or, if you're a native speaker, would you say *to bail out* is also correct here?

Comment: This is more about programming, not Computer Science and even more about English language usage.. Below excerpt 

"The most abrupt way to bail out is by calling the Standard C abort function, as in:"
 *if (something really bad happened)    abort();*

You can also check at [SO] by searching for "bail out", for example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8311723/strategy-for-bail-out-when-dealing-with-pipes-fork
or https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/intro.html

Comment: Yes, “bail out” is correct here. Check [a dictionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/bail_out). It can be transitive or intransitive. When it's intransitive, it can mean “to get oneself out of a difficult situation”.

Comment: That's a slightly different usage of `bail`. For this one, see the examples under "phrasal verbs" section 1.1 in https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/bail#h70131995116240: "discontinue an activity"

Answer (score 1):

I understand "to bail out" as to give up permanently; "to back out" is to give up some track, possibly to try something else.